# Error with C code: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) when iterating through pointer of memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, runtime-error

I'm working on a C programming project for school and it was working fine but now all of a sudden when it's trying to access a number in a block of memory under numbers_array[j] it will not access index 2 of the array and keeps giving me the error in the title

I have been debugging for about an hour and cannot figure what is wrong. It will factor number at index 0 and index 1 fine but after that the program crashes. Any idea what is wrong?

The error can be found in the loop after the declaration of factor_struct under the comment Requirement 2.

My code for a number factoring program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

/* Requirement 2:
Creating a struct with serveral pieces of data */
struct factor_struct {
    int number, count;
    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    double time_to_factor;
    double times_array[];
};

/* Function header decleration */
void factor(struct factor_struct *fs);

/* The main program loop */
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

/* Intializing the variables we'll be using during the run loop */
int input, number, continue_loop_one = TRUE, continue_loop_two = TRUE;
int *numbers_array;

/* Printing the welcome message to the screen */
printf("Welcome to Factor Factory!\n\n");

/* Asking how many numbers the user would like to factor*/
printf("How many different numbers would you like to factor?\n");

/* Start of LOOP_1: Ask user to input the amount of numbers to factor.
   This will let us allocate the proper amount of memory */
LOOP_1: do {
    printf("Please enter a number from 1 to 10: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("\n");
    
    /* Check if user input is between 1 and 10, if not return to start of LOOP_1 */
    if(input < 1 || input > 10) {
        printf("%d isn't a valid number...don't play games with me human. Try again! \n\n", input);
        
        /* Need to flush the incorrect input from the buffer or else scanf will cause a continuous loop*/
        fflush(stdin);
        goto LOOP_1;
    }
    
    /* Break out of the loop and continue our program */
    continue_loop_one = FALSE;
    
} while (continue_loop_one == TRUE);

/* Requirement 4:
   Intialize our numbers array with the correct amount of memory */
numbers_array = (int*) calloc(input, sizeof(int));

/* Check if memory was allocated properly */
if (numbers_array == NULL) {
    printf("Error: Memory not allocated. Closing program...\n");
    exit(0);
}

/* Requirement 1:
   Asking the user to enter the numbers that we will be using our algorithm for to get their factors */
LOOP_2: do {
    printf("Excellent! Lets get started...");
    printf("enter %d number(s) between 2 and 1,000,000,000.\n", input);
    
    /* Variable to track how many numbers have been input just incase a user enters an invalid number*/
    int entered_number_count = 0;
    
    LOOP_3: for(int i = 0 + entered_number_count; i < input; i++) {
        printf("Number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &number);
    
        if (number < 2 || number > 1000000000) {
            printf("%d isn't a valid number...don't play games with me human. Try again! \n\n", number);
            fflush(stdin);
            goto LOOP_3;
        }
        
        /* Assinging a number to the value at the proper memory location in the numbers_array */
        numbers_array[i] = number;
        
        /* Incrementing the amount of entered numbers */
        entered_number_count++;
        }
    
    /* Break out the loop and continue our program */
    continue_loop_two = FALSE;
    
} while(continue_loop_two == TRUE);

printf("\n");

/* Requirement 2:
   Declaring our factor_struct for use */
struct factor_struct fs;
fs.count = 0;

/* For each number in the array, assign it to fs.number and factor it by passing it to our factor function
   Each pass over the array will reassign fs.number */

for(int j = 0; j < input; j++) {
    fs.number = numbers_array[j]; // **ERROR APPEARS IF INDEX J > 1**
    factor(&fs);
    fs.count++;
}

/* Requirement 3:
   Using a pointer to move through time_array which will calculate
   the total time to factor all numbers */
double total_time = 0.0;
double *ptr = fs.times_array;
for(; *ptr; ++ptr) { total_time += *ptr; }
printf("Total computation time: %f seconds. \n\n", total_time);

/* Ask the user if they would like to continue or quit the program*/
printf("Would you like to continue factoring numbers?\n");
printf("Enter 'y' to continue or 'q' to quit: ");

/* Control loop that handles the continue or quit commands */
char c;
while(c != 'q') {
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if(c == 'y') {
        printf("\n");
        goto LOOP_1;
    }
}

/* Thank the user and quit the program */
printf("\n");
printf("Thank you for using Factor Factory!\n");
printf("Closing program...\n\n");

/* Requirement 4:
   Deallocating the memory for the numbers_array */
free(numbers_array);
return 0;
}

/* Requirement 5:
Taking data and passing it through the facotring algorithm */
void factor(struct factor_struct *fs) {

/* Marking the starting time of the function */
fs->start = clock();

printf("Factors of %d: ", fs->number);

/* Algorithm for finding all factors of our number */
for(int i = 1; i <= fs->number/2; i++) {
    if (fs->number % i == 0) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}

printf("%d\n", fs->number);

/* Marking the ending time of the function */
fs->end = clock();

/* Calculating the total time it took to find all factors*/
    fs->time_to_factor = (double)(fs->end - fs->start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    fs->times_array[fs->count] = fs->time_to_factor;
}
```

Comment: `double times_array[];`. That's wrong. That's called a flexible array. It is meant to be used when dynamically allocating the containing struct with the allocation size larger than the struct with the extra size used for the array. But you don't have any such dynamic allocation so `fs->times_array[fs->count]` is accessing invalid memory.

Comment: Also, your use of `goto` is very bad practice. It makes the code fragile, difficult to read and hard to debug. There's no reason at all that there be any `goto` statements in this code (there are very limited good uses of `goto` but not how you are using it).

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the help. Any tips on what I should be doing instead of using goto in order to traverse back to the top of a loop?

Comment: It's hard to comment on each goto because the code really needs non-trivial restructuring. Example: for `LOOP_3` you should change to use a `while` loop. The terminating condition should just check that the `entered_number_count` has reached the expected value. Inside the body the `entered_number_count` should only be incremented if the entered number is valid. That way, the loop condition naturally controls whether the loop continues or exits without any `goto`.

Comment: @kaylum Appreciate the info. Will start the refactoring process now.